# Python - Creating a "for" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner and I have a question how to make a "for" loop to check the following condition for me:

- if the folder does not exist, create it
- if there is a folder, create a file in it
- and check if the folder exists again
  a) the folder exists, create a file in it
  b) does not exist, create a folder, create a file

```
import os
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(now)

directory = "D:/Dir/Dir_" + now
print(directory) # D:/Dir/Dir_2021-11-12

if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
    print("Created folder: " + directory)
else:
    print("Folder exists")

now_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
print("Current date: " + now_datetime)

full_path = directory + "/file_" + now_datetime + ".txt"
print(full_path)  # D:/Dir/Dir_2021-11-12/file_2021-11-12_1000.txt

output = print("Something ...")
print(output)
plik = open(full_path,"w+")
plik.write(output)
plik.close()
```

Ultimately, I would like to make a process that will run all the time, because I want to read messages from the server. So, for example, when I get messages from the server, it will write them to a file and then the loop will check if there is a folder for a given day. If it exists, new files will be created in this folder. Until a new folder appears. Then the files will start falling into a new folder.
Can anyone help me? Somehow guide as the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Sounds mor e like you need an `if` condition, not a `for` loop.

Comment: You could check the source of the logging module and see how the [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler) handles the creation of a new logfile after midnight (or rather the renaming of the current log file) - then adapt that to create a new folder after midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a while-loop, either running infinitely or until a certain condition is meet. See this simple example:

```
import time
x = 0
while x < 10: # while(true)
  x += 1
  time.sleep(1)
  print(x)
```

Add the time.sleep to make the loop sleep so that it does not run continuously